# Algorithm in Ruby to trigger a method based on presence of certain texts

Tags: ruby, string, algorithm, text

I don't know if it can be called an algorithm but i think its close. 
I will be pulling data from an API that will have certain words in the title, eg:

1. Great Software 2.0 Download Now
2. Buy Great Software for just $10
3. Great Software Torrent Download

So, i want to do different things based on the presence of certain words such as Download, Buy etc. For eg, if it has the word 'buy' in it, i would like to extract the word buy and the amount value that is present in the title and show it in another div, so in this case it would be "Buy for $10" or "Buy $10" etc. I can do if/else as well but I don't want to use if else because there could be more such conditions in the future. So what i am thinking about is using the send method. eg:

```
def buy(string)
  'Buy for just' + string.scan(/\$\d+/).first
end

def whichkeyword(title)
  send (title.scan(/(download|buy)/i)[0][0]).downcase.to_sym, title
end

whichkeyword('Buy this software for $10 now')
```

is there a better way to do this? Or is this even a good way to do it? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think you already have done a pretty good job in figuring out the appropriate solution.

Comment: I found this hard to answer. Is there something in particular that you would like to improve about your solution? Perhaps consider providing more detail around your motivation to write this code in the first place. Currently your going to get a whole stack of vaguely similar answers that are slightly different implementations  of regex methods. Throw in some options on meta programming and I would not think there is much scope to add value here.

Comment: @Stewart Actually I am not a pro so I wanted to know if this is the proper ruby way of doing it. What i wanted to ask is how would you go about solving a similar problem, without using if/else.

Comment: @HarshTrivedi just looking for a better way of doing it, if there is one.

Comment: @CarySwoveland just did thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use `send` if and only you are to call *private* method, use `public_send` otherwise.

In this particular case metaprogramming is an overkill. It requires too much redundant code, plus it requires *the code* to be changed for new items. I would go with building a hash like:

```
@hash = { 'buy' => { text: 'Buy for just %{placeholder}', re: /\$\d+/ } }
```

This hash might be places somewhere outside of *the code*, e. g. it might be stored in `yml` file near the code and loaded in advance. That way you might be able to change a behaviour without modifying the code, that is handy for instance in `gem`.

As we have a hash defined/loaded, I would call the method:

```
def format string
  key = string[/#{Regexp.union(@hash.keys).source}/i].downcase
  puts @hash[key][:text] % { placeholder: string[@hash[key][:re]] }
end
```

Yielding:

```
▶ format("Buy this software for $10 now")
#⇒ Buy for just $10
```

There are many advantages over declaring methods, e. g. now matches might contain spaces, you might easily add/remove matchers etc.

Comment: thanks, this looks better and simpler too. i didn't know about public_send.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your algorithm can work, but has some troubles in it, like what if no keyword is applied.

I have two solutions for you:

**NLP**
If you want to do it much more dynamic, you can use **NLP - Natural language Processing**.  NLP will find main words in you sentence and then you can find the good solution for each.
A good gem for that is [Treat](https://github.com/louismullie/treat) that you can use with [stanford-core-nlp](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/). After processing the data you can find the **verbs** and even **synonyms** in the sentence and figure out what to do.

```
sentence('Buy this software for $10 now').verbs # ['buy']
```

**Simple Hash**
This solution is less dynamic, but much more simple. Like you did with the scan, just use Constant to manage your keywords, and the output from them(I would do it with lambdas). you can also add default to the hash

```
KEYWORDS = Hash.new('Default Title').merge(
             buy: -> { },
             download: -> { }
           )
KEYWORDS[sentence[/(#{KEYWORDS.keys.join('|')})/i].downcase]
```

Comment: `to_sym` is required on the key for lookup; it’s better use `Regexp.union` rather than simple `join '|'`.

Comment: yeah of course, i will use an `if` there but only once, if it doesn't match anything, then it will just return a default text, if it matches, then it would call that method. natural language processing sounds like a good idea. but how heavy is it? its a basic app i am building using the Roda gem and keeping the database as lean as possible is one of the goals as well. I think the solution you have provided is simpler than what i have written in my question, i will try it out.

Comment: @mudasobwa you are right about the to_sym, you can also use HashWithIndifferentAccess. About `Regexp.union`, I think it could be a problem with case sensitive(/reg/**i**). @b-a The NLP is not using your db, it opens another one, The simple solution can work for you now, but remember the nlp when you want to expand your project, I use it on my heroku basic server with no problem.

Comment: There is no `HashWithIndifferentAccess` in Ruby and the question is not marked with Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution is good enough.
The only thing that looks strange is `scan(/(download|buy)/i)[0][0]`.

As for me I don't very much like using `[]` syntax in Ruby.
I think using `scan` here is not necessary.
What about

```
def whichkeyword(title)
  title =~ /(download|buy)/i
  send $1.downcase.to_sym, title unless $1.nil?
end
```

**UPDATE**

```
def whichkeyword(title)
  action = title[/(download|buy)/i]
  public_send action.downcase.to_sym, title if action
end
```

Comment: Discover [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with regexp param: `title[/(download|buy)/i] #⇒ 'Buy'`. Also, please never use `send` when `public_send` is applicable.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know about `public_send` existing.

Comment: I wasn't aware of public_send either. @Aleksey thanks, your version definitely looks cleaner.